# What is the byte format of an 8-bit monaural WAV file?

Tags: audio, format, byte, wav

**Setup**:  WAV 8bit 8kHz mono PCM file.

By spec, 8-bit bytes are unsigned [0,255].  Is the byte value 2's compliment?  Is it simply binary offset?  **What EXACTLY is the byte format?**

[MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dawate/2009/06/23/intro-to-audio-programming-part-2-demystifying-the-wav-format/) says the byte is in 2's compliment. Yet, [DSP discussions](https://www.dsprelated.com/showthread/comp.dsp/71057-1.php) say binary offset, meaning zero amplitude is 127?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

8-bit WAV is the only format which is unsigned. The linked MSDN blog is wrong. I can verify this from experience and also the wikipedia page for WAV files https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV has a mention.

So if you were to consider a full scale sine wave, the zero crossing would be at 127, the positive peak would be at 255, and the negative peak would be at 0 or 1, depending on implementation (although you should account for the possibility of it being zero)